# "an entertainment"

Tags: countable-nouns

I'm reading Neil Postman's *Amusing Ourselves to Death* and I came across an interesting usage of the word entertainment.

> "The first is that on television, religion, like everything else, is presented, quite simply and without apology, as an entertainment."

I would have figured he'd truncate the sentence and use the verb: "as entertainment". I have never seen "an entertainment" before. What is this called grammatically?

Comment: The tag on this site is countable-nouns

Comment: It's a rare use of "entertainment" as countable, but perfectly legitimate.  Using it in this way emphasizes that "religion" is treated the same as a sitcom or drama.

Comment: @HotLicks That makes perfect sense thank you! Can you post as answer please?